# R: Selecting first of n consecutive rows above a certain threshold value

Tags: r, dataframe, row, dplyr

I have a data frame with MRN, dates, and a test value.

I need to select all the ***first*** rows per MRN that have ***three*** consecutive values above 0.5.

This is an example version of the data:

```
   MRN Collected_Date   ANC
1  001     2015-01-02 0.345
2  001     2015-01-03 0.532
3  001     2015-01-04 0.843
4  001     2015-01-05 0.932
5  002     2015-03-03 0.012
6  002     2015-03-05 0.022
7  002     2015-03-06 0.543
8  002     2015-03-07 0.563
9  003     2015-08-02 0.343
10 003     2015-08-03 0.500
11 003     2015-08-04 0.734
12 003     2015-08-05 0.455
13 004     2014-01-02 0.001
14 004     2014-01-03 0.500
15 004     2014-01-04 0.562
16 004     2014-01-05 0.503
```

Example code:

```
df <- data.frame(MRN = c('001','001','001','001',
                         '002','002','002','002',
                         '003','003','003','003',
                         '004','004','004','004'), 
                 Collected_Date = as.Date(c('01-02-2015','01-03-2015','01-04-2015','01-05-2015',
                                            '03-03-2015','03-05-2015','03-06-2015','03-07-2015',
                                            '08-02-2015','08-03-2015','08-04-2015','08-05-2015',
                                            '01-02-2014','01-03-2014','01-04-2014','01-05-2014'), 
                                            format = '%m-%d-%Y'), 
                 ANC = as.numeric(c('0.345','0.532','0.843','0.932',
                         '0.012','0.022','0.543','0.563',
                         '0.343','0.500','0.734','0.455',
                         '0.001','0.500','0.562','0.503')))
```

Currently, I am using a very awkward approach using the lag function to calculate the date difference, then filter for all values >= 0.5, and then sum up the values, which helps to select the date of the THIRD value. I then substract two days to get the date of the first value:

```
   df %>% group_by(MRN) %>% 
    mutate(., days_diff = abs(Collected_Date[1] - Collected_Date)) %>% 
        filter(ANC >= 0.5) %>%
            mutate(days = days_diff + lag((days_diff))) %>%
                filter(days == 5) %>%
                    mutate(Collected_Date = Collected_Date - 2) %>%
                        select(MRN, Collected_Date)
```

Output:

Source: local data frame [2 x 2]
Groups: MRN

```
  MRN Collected_Date
1 001     2015-01-03
2 004     2014-01-03
```

There must be a way simpler / more elegant way. Also, it does not give accurate results if there are gaps between the test dates.

My desired output for this example is:

```
   MRN Collected_Date   ANC     
1  001     2015-01-03 0.532
2  004     2014-01-03 0.500
```

So if at least three consecutive test values are >= 0.5, the date of the FIRST value should be returned.

If there are not at least three consecutive values >= 0.5, NA should be returned.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Thank you very much!

Comment: Look at `cumany` - it is perfect for this situation.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The easiest way is to use the `zoo` library in conjunction with `dplyr`. Within the `zoo` package there is a function called `rollapply`, we can use this to calculate a function value for a window of time.

In this example, we could apply the window to calculate the minimum of the next three values, and then apply the logic specified.

```
df %>% group_by(MRN) %>%
  mutate(ANC=rollapply(ANC, width=3, min, align="left", fill=NA, na.rm=TRUE)) %>%
  filter(ANC >= 0.5) %>%  
  filter(row_number() == 1)

#   MRN Collected_Date   ANC
# 1 001     2015-01-03 0.532
# 2 004     2014-01-03 0.500
```

---

In the code above we have used `rollapply` to calculate the minimum of the next 3 items. To see how this works compare the following:

```
rollapply(1:6, width=3, min, align="left", fill=NA) # [1]  1  2  3  4 NA NA
rollapply(1:6, width=3, min, align="center", fill=NA) # [1] NA  1  2  3  4 NA
rollapply(1:6, width=3, min, align="right", fill=NA) # [1] NA NA  1  2  3  4
```

So in our example, we have aligned from the left, so it starts from the current location and looks forward to the next 2 values.

Lastly we filter by the appropriate values, and take the first observation of each group.

Answer (score 3):

Base approach:

Use `rle` to find sequences of 3 or more and grab the first one

```
df <- data.frame(MRN = c('001','001','001','001','002','002','002','002','003','003','003','003','004','004','004','004'), Collected_Date = as.Date(c('01-02-2015','01-03-2015','01-04-2015','01-05-2015', '03-03-2015','03-05-2015','03-06-2015','03-07-2015', '08-02-2015','08-03-2015','08-04-2015','08-05-2015', '01-02-2014','01-03-2014','01-04-2014','01-05-2014'), format = '%m-%d-%Y'), ANC = as.numeric(c('0.345','0.532','0.843','0.932', '0.012','0.022','0.543','0.563', '0.343','0.500','0.734','0.455', '0.001','0.500','0.562','0.503')))

df[as.logical(with(df, ave(ANC, MRN, FUN = function(x)
   cumsum(x >= .5 & with(rle(x >= .5), rep(lengths, lengths)) >= 3) == 1))), ]

#    MRN Collected_Date   ANC 
# 2  001     2015-01-03 0.532
# 14 004     2014-01-03 0.500
```

Maybe this version is easier to understand

```
df[as.logical(with(df, ave(ANC, MRN, FUN = function(x) {
     r <- rle(x >= .5)
     r <- rep(r$lengths, r$lengths)
     cumsum(r == 3 & x >= .5) == 1
    }))), ]
```

edit

```
df <- df[c(1:4,4,4,4,5,5,5,5:16), ]
df[as.logical(with(df, ave(ANC, MRN, FUN = function(x)
  cumsum(x >= .5 & with(rle(x >= .5), rep(lengths, lengths)) >= 3) == 1))), ]

#    MRN Collected_Date   ANC
# 2  001     2015-01-03 0.532
# 14 004     2014-01-03 0.500
```

Comment: This will also find runs of length 3 where ANC < 0.5 (not just >=), and will skip runs of length greater than 3 (will only give you runs of exactly 3)

Answer (score 2):

We can create an auxiliary function which given a vector `x` returns a vector indicating the number of consecutive values above a given threshold:

```
high_run <- function(x, threshold) {
    high <- x >= threshold
    streak <- high[1]
    for(h in high[2:length(high)]){
        streak <- c(streak, streak[length(streak)]*h + h)
    }
    run
}
```

as well as a function which returns the starting index of the first run of a particular length:

```
high_run_start <- function(x, threshold, run){
    match(run, high_run(x, threshold)) - run + 1
}
```

We can then use this latter function to select the appropriate rows of the original dataframe:

```
> df %>% group_by(MRN) %>%
+ filter(row_number()==high_run_start(ANC,0.5,3))
Source: local data frame [2 x 3]
Groups: MRN

  MRN Collected_Date   ANC
1 001     2015-01-03 0.532
2 004     2014-01-03 0.500
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a `ddply` solution (sorry, I'm not up-to-date with the `%>%` syntax, but perhaps it could also be applied).

I'm unsure if it's "elegant" in the sense that you mean, but it will make sense upon reading it a second time (which to me is more important than a one-liner), and is robust to missing dates etc.

The key is to use `rle` (run length encoding) to look for 'runs' of `ANC >= 0.5` where the run is at least length 3. This takes care of the 'consecutive' part. we save this into `r`.

Then `r.i` gives the index in the first run that is of length 3 or more, and where the value of the run is `TRUE`.

To get the index in `x` you just `sum` the run lengths up to but not including the run we are interested in, and add 1 to get to the start (that's the `sum(r$lengths[1:(r.i - 1)])` and the `+1`).

```
ddply(df,
.(MRN),
function (x) {
    r <- rle(x$ANC >= 0.5) # find 'runs' of x$ANC >= 0.5
    # find index of first run of length >=3 with ANC >= .5
    r.i <- which(r$lengths >= 3 & r$values)[1] 
    if (!is.na(r.i)) {
        # get index of first row in that run and return it.
        return(x[sum(r$lengths[seq_len(r.i - 1)]) + 1, ])
    }
    return(NULL)
})
```

It will make better sense if you extract e.g. `x <- subset(df, MRN == '001')` and step through to see what `r`, `r.i` look like.