# How do I get the column names for ALL the nth CONSECUTIVE occurrence of a value in a data table row using R

Tags: r

I'm looking for a way, to determine "join", "churn", and "rejoin" dates for clients in a data frame (clients as row labels, month/year as column labels, earnings as values) where:

- The first month with a non-zero earnings value for a client = join date
- If there are 13 consecutive months with no earnings (zero value), then the 13th month is considered a "churn" month.
- If, after a "churn" month has occurred, there is a non-zero value for that client, then the corresponding month in that column is the "rejoin" month.
- If there is another 13 months with no earnings AFTER a rejoin month, then the last month in that block of 13 zero value columns is another churn month

I could probably hack this together with For loops (see pseudo-code below), but I'm wondering if there is a more elegant way to do it with apply functions or with the dplyr package.

So, data frame looks like this:

```
    > clients
                  Jan08 Feb08 Mar08 Apr08 May08 ... 
    client 1      1     0     0     0     0     ... 
    client 2      0     -6    6    -6     6     ... 
    client 3      28    4     108   93    3.85  ... 
                   ............
```

and I'm looking to run logic like this:

```
    For each client {
      For each month {
        If the value this month == 0 {
          If the previous 12 months values all == 0* {
            If there is a non-zero value exactly 13 months before {
              then mark the current month as a churn month
            }
          }
        }
        Else {
          If this is the first non zero value in the row {
            then mark the current month as the join month
          }
        Else {
          If this is the first non-zero value in 13 or more months {
            then mark this as a rejoin month
          }
        }
      }
    }
```

*NOTE: As with client 2, I could have negative values, so I can't just sum up values to determine if proceeding values are all zero.

Any direction on this would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I think the best approach to this problem is to change it to a long dataframe rather than a wide one. For example, it could look something like this:

```
clients <- data.frame(
  client = c(rep(1, 15)),
  month = rep(1:15, 1),
  activity = c(1, rep(0, 13), 1)
)
```

Which looks like this:

```
> clients
   client month activity
1       1     1        1
2       1     2        0
3       1     3        0
4       1     4        0
5       1     5        0
6       1     6        0
7       1     7        0
8       1     8        0
9       1     9        0
10      1    10        0
11      1    11        0
12      1    12        0
13      1    13        0
14      1    14        0
15      1    15        1
```

Once you have done this then you can treat each client seperately via `dplyr` `groupby` method. All that remains is to make use of window functions to process the logic you have provided.

To make use of window functions I use `library(zoo)` and the `rollapply` method. This approach is something I used in [another solution here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31373256/r-selecting-first-of-n-consecutive-rows-above-a-certain-threshold-value/31373578#31373578), where you can see it being used in a similar problem.

From here we can simply apply the logic that we're after. So an extremely messy version could look like this:

```
clients %>% group_by(client) %>%
  mutate(
    isChurn = rollapply(activity, 13, function(x) {
      all(x == 0)
    }, align="right", fill=NA), # if there are 13 consecutive months with no earnings

    isRejoin = rollapply(activity, 14, function(x) {
      all(x[1:13] == 0) & x[14] != 0
    }, align="right", fill=NA)
  )
```

Which has the output based on the my `data.frame`:

```
Source: local data frame [15 x 5]
Groups: client

   client month activity isChurn isRejoin
1       1     1        1      NA       NA
2       1     2        0      NA       NA
3       1     3        0      NA       NA
4       1     4        0      NA       NA
5       1     5        0      NA       NA
6       1     6        0      NA       NA
7       1     7        0      NA       NA
8       1     8        0      NA       NA
9       1     9        0      NA       NA
10      1    10        0      NA       NA
11      1    11        0      NA       NA
12      1    12        0      NA       NA
13      1    13        0   FALSE       NA
14      1    14        0    TRUE    FALSE
15      1    15        1   FALSE     TRUE
```

I'm not sure if for the churn month you only want to mark the first occurrence as a churn month or not. But I think this will get you there and you should be able to figure out the rest.

Comment: Minor simplification rollapply instances: `rollapplyr(activity == 0, 13, all, fill=NA)` and `rollapplyr(activity == 0, 14, function(x) all(x[-14]) && !x[14], fill = NA)` .

Comment: Having some issues getting this to run.  I get a 'wrong sing in 'by' argument error, which seems to indicate that the data types are not working with grouping.

I should note that in the actual data, the clients are "client 1", "client 2"... they have actual character string names, so even when I flatten out the table, the client column is of type character.

Comment: If you could provide a reproducible example then I'll have a look.