# Find the first set of consecutive integers in a vector

Tags: r, vector

I have a dataset where I am trying to find the first instance in a consecutive set of rows that are identical.  So let's say given this dataset:

```
df <- data.frame(trial = c(1:16), DV = c(2, 3, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1))
```

If I were looking for the first integer in `df$DV` to repeat itself 5 times (for example), it would spit out "4".

I've tried a few things using the solutions found here ([R: Selecting first of n consecutive rows above a certain threshold value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31373256/r-selecting-first-of-n-consecutive-rows-above-a-certain-threshold-value)), which is a similar problem, but I'm stuck.  Any suggestions?

Thanks for your help in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This does it

```
with(rle(df$DV), values[which(lengths >= 5)[1]])
```

If there is no consecutive chunks with a length >= 5, you get `NA`.

Comment: Ha!  I was thinking about it way too hard.  This is a simple, elegant solution.  Thank you!